# Creating rotation pattern in libreoffice in specific range

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I would like to use the following code in libreoffice imported from excel:
I get the error at the first Loop.

```
Sub twelve()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y, w As Integer
x = 5

y = 0
For x = 5 To 13
    Sheet1.Cells(x, (3 + y)).Select

    ActiveCell.Value = "D"
        If y (does not equal) 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "O"
        End If
        If y = 2 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "O"
        End If
        If y = 3 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = "O"
        End If
        If y = 4 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value = "N"
        End If
        If y = 5 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value = "N"
        End If
        If y = 6 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Value = "N"
        End If
        If y = 7 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value = "O"
        End If
        If y = 8 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Value = "O"
        End If
        If y = 9 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "O"
        End If
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Value = "D"
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)).Value = "O"
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = "N"
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11)).Value = "o"
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14)).Value = "d"
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17)).Value = "o"
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20)).Value = "n"
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23)).Value = "o"
        If y = 0 Then
            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "D"
            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 29)).Value = "O"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 30).Value = "N"
        End If
        If y = 1 Then
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "D"
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 29)).Value = "O"
        End If

If y = 2 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "D"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28)).Value = "O"
End If
If y = 3 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "D"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27).Value = "O"
End If
If y = 4 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "D"

End If

If y = 5 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25)).Value = "D"

End If
If y = 6 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = "D"

End If
y = y + 1

Next x

w = 0
For x = 14 To 21
Sheet1.Cells(x, (3 + w)).Select
'ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)

ActiveCell.Value = "N"
If w (does not equal) 0 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "O"
End If
If w = 2 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "O"
End If
If w = 3 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = "O"
End If
If w = 4 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value = "D"
End If
If w = 5 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Value = "D"
End If
If w = 6 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Value = "D"
End If
If w = 7 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value = "O"
End If
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)).Value = "N"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)).Value = "O"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = "D"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11)).Value = "o"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14)).Value = "n"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17)).Value = "o"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20)).Value = "d"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23)).Value = "o"
If w = 0 Then
            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "N"
            Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 29)).Value = "O"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 30).Value = "N"
        End If
        If w = 1 Then
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "N"
        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 29)).Value = "O"
        End If

If w = 2 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "N"
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28)).Value = "O"
End If
If w = 3 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "N"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27).Value = "O"
End If
If w = 4 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26)).Value = "N"

End If

If w = 5 Then
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25)).Value = "N"

End If
If w = 6 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value = "O"

End If



w = w + 1

Next x
End Sub
```

source from this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZvLdOboKXk

Unfortunately, i was able to get by on VBA excel but libreoffice even refuse the loop module which makes the whole task very difficult.

Comment: It will work better if you write it in the correct language! A good place to start learning LibreOffice Basic is https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.

Comment: What do you think the operator `If y (does not equal) 0 Then` and `If w (does not equal) 0 Then` should do? This may come as a surprise to you, but in this procedure, cycles are simply not needed - neither the first for Y, nor the second for W. Just write out the sequence of actions line by line and get rid of both `For ... Next` and the set of `If-Then- EndIf`. Of course, the code will work if the sheet cells are [**accessed according to the rules**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/guide/read_write_values.html).